# Flutter How to get List<String> _list Array strings from Rest API using JSON

Tags: json, api, rest, flutter, dictionary

I am a newbe in Flutter and I want to get data from my mysql and how to get the data of 'Facebook',  'Twitter', 'Youtube' from my mysql db ?

I want to load data into _tags1 widget from my mysql data.

```
 final List<String> _list = [ 'Facebook',  'Twitter', 'Youtube'];
```

_list array value should be from my mysql data.

Here is my full code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tags/flutter_tags.dart';



void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Tags Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Tags'),
    );
  }
}



class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>{


  bool _symmetry = false;
  bool _removeButton = true;
  bool _singleItem = true;
  bool _startDirection = false;
  bool _horizontalScroll = true;
  int _column = 0;
  double _fontSize = 14;


  List _icon = [Icons.home, Icons.language, Icons.headset];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _items = _list.toList();
  }
  List _items;


  final List<String> _list = [ 'Facebook',  'Twitter', 'Youtube'];

  final GlobalKey<TagsState> _tagStateKey = GlobalKey<TagsState>();



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
             child: Container(
                child:  _tags1,
              )
          )
              );
  }

  Widget get _tags1 {
    return Tags(
      key: _tagStateKey,
      symmetry: _symmetry,
      columns: _column,
      horizontalScroll: _horizontalScroll,
      //verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up, textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      heightHorizontalScroll: 60 * (_fontSize / 14),
      itemCount: _items.length,
      itemBuilder: (index) {
        final item = _items[index];

        return ItemTags(
          key: Key(index.toString()),
          index: index,
          title: item,
          pressEnabled: true,
          activeColor: Colors.blueGrey[600],
          singleItem: _singleItem,
          splashColor: Colors.green,
          combine: ItemTagsCombine.withTextBefore,
          image: index > 0 && index < 5
              ? ItemTagsImage(
            //image: AssetImage("img/p$index.jpg"),
              child: Image.network(
                "http://www.clipartpanda.com/clipart_images/user-66327738/download",
                width: 16 * _fontSize / 14,
                height: 16 * _fontSize / 14,
              ))
              : (1 == 1
              ? ItemTagsImage(
            image: NetworkImage(
                "https://d32ogoqmya1dw8.cloudfront.net/images/serc/empty_user_icon_256.v2.png"),
          )
              : null),
          icon: (item == '0' || item == '1' || item == '2')
              ? ItemTagsIcon(
            icon: _icon[int.parse(item)],
          )
              : null,
          removeButton: _removeButton
              ? ItemTagsRemoveButton(
            onRemoved: () {
              setState(() {
                _items.removeAt(index);
              });
              return true;
            },
          )
              : null,
          textScaleFactor:
          utf8.encode(item.substring(0, 1)).length > 2 ? 0.8 : 1,
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: _fontSize,
          ),
          onPressed: (item) => print(item),
        );
      },
    );
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a Get request on your API endpoint. This endpoint will return your JSON with your string list. After receiving, you need to decode the json to your List. Here is an example:

```
// Getting API Data using Dio package:
var response = await dio.get(yourApiUrl);

//parsing your json to string list
List<String> stringList = (jsonDecode(response) as List<dynamic>).cast<String>();
```

Comment: List<String> stringList = (jsonDecode(response) as List<dynamic>).cast<String>(); -- This line throwing error

The argument type 'Response<Dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'